# Split HTML in a certain form of list in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x

For a django project i need to generate from the Django Website a kind of complex Word document.

I started using Docx-Template that do the job great but i encountered a problem:

For certain "spot" in the word template i need to brake Django rich texte (HTML) in something usable for Docx Template
So i went into transforming my richtext in a list that can have two types of elements (to keep the order of the blocs) : ["some paragraphs","('list',['first elt of the list for bullet','second','ect...")]

For now i have two function : one that break the HTML and one that transform it

My "HTML Breaking function" is like that :

```
def decoupe_html (raw_html):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(raw_html,"html.parser")
    arbre=[]
    #decoupe en grand bloc HTML
    for elt in soup:
        arbre.append(elt)
    print(arbre)
    #On parcours chaque elt pour le transformer en truc compréhensible par Word dans une liste
    for elt in arbre:
        #recup du tag de début du "chunk"
        tag=elt.name
        #traitement des paragraphe de texte
        if tag == "p":
            texte=elt.text
            place=arbre.index(elt)
            arbre[place]=texte
        #traitement des listes
        elif tag == "ul":
            list_elt=[]
            enfants = elt.findChildren()
            #on récupère tous les elt de la liste
            for chld in enfants:
                list_elt.append(chld.text)
            place=arbre.index(elt)
            arbre[place]=("list",list_elt)
    return(arbre)
```

But i have trouble in "breaking" more complex list with multi level like for example this html :

```
<p>pfoizepfkjze</p>
<ul>
    <li>blabla
    <ul>
        <li>bla2
        <ul>
            <li>bla3
            <ul>
                <li>bla4</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>rebla</li>
</ul>
```

what should i change in my code to keep my data structure and get for example :
arbre = ['pfoizepfkjze',('list',['blabla',('list',['bla2',('list',['bla3',('list',['bla4'])])]),'rebla'])]

Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Are you trying to get the values from a website you do not have control of or build a Django function to read the HTML of a page generated by the same Django application?

Comment: I'm trying to extract data from my Django Databse but the data stored is HTML (CKeditor store Richtext in HTML format) i have trouble to "break" multi level list into my format presented in the post :)